# Implementing a simple modal in Ionic without standard Ionic component, getting error

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I have created a page in Ionic. Now on this page I wanted to call a simple only css modal box. So I added some CSS and HTML code`in`page.html`and`page.scss` but when I click on the button it says

> Uncaught (in promise): invalid views to insert

Below is my code:

**page.html**

```
<div class="css-script-ads" align="center">

  <a href="#target-content" id="button">Open A Modal</a>
  <div id="target-content"> <a href="#" class="close"></a>
    <div id="target-inner">
      <h2>CSS Modal</h2>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur lobortis, justo tempor elementum malesuada, ligula sapien convallis nulla, quis mollis augue tortor tristique mauris. Mauris sed nunc in ante molestie pulvinar ac in orci. </div>
  </div>
```

page.scss

```
page-webpage {
    #target-content {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        pointer-events: none;
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transition: opacity 200ms;
        transition: opacity 200ms;
      }

      #target-content:target {
        pointer-events: all;
        opacity: 1;
      }

      #target-content #target-inner {
        position: absolute;
        display: block;
        padding: 48px;
        line-height: 1.8;
        width: 70%;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
        -ms-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
        transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
        box-shadow: 0px 12px 24px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
        background: white;
        color: #34495E;
      }

      #target-content #target-inner h2 { margin-top: 0; }

      #target-content #target-inner code { font-weight: bold; }

      #target-content a.close {
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        background-color: #34495E;
        opacity: 0.5;
        -webkit-transition: opacity 200ms;
        transition: opacity 200ms;
      }

      #target-content a.close:hover { opacity: 0.4; }

      body {
        background-color: #ECF0F1;
        color: #444;
      }

      #button {
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
        -ms-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
        transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
        padding: 16px 24px;
        border-radius: 1px;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-size: 24px;
        display: block;
        color: white;
        background-color: #34495E;
        text-align: center;
        font-weight: 100;
        -webkit-transition: box-shadow 200ms;
        transition: box-shadow 200ms;
        border-radius: 4px;
      }

      #button:hover { box-shadow: 0px 12px 24px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2); }
}
```

How can I get this to work without error?

I don't want to use Ionic pre-made component for some reason.

Comment: Remove `href="#target-content"`

Comment: if i am removing it, popup is not opening

Comment: It modify the url so Ionic will throw an error. Just remove it and add onClick function. Show and hide Modal by `ngIf`

Answer (score 0):

try like this

**remove** `href="#target-content"`

and **replace** this `(click)="openModal({charNum: 0})"`

**import** `ModalController`

and put it `openModal(characterNum) {

```
let modal = this.modalCtrl.create(FeedsPage, characterNum);
modal.present();
```

}`

learn more about [Ionic-Modals](https://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#modals)